# How do companies open offices in developing countries?

Tags: company, business, outsourcing

I've been interviewing for dozens of software development companies in my city which is located in a developing country. The companies are run by people that reside in my country and share the same nationality as me. Also, they consist of mainly software developers while the management is mostly located in Western Europe (because of lowering the labor costs etc).

But, I was wondering how do people from my country reach out to this big and wealthy companies in order for them to open a branch in my country?

Some of the software developers were previously working as individuals for these companies and after building trust, they managed to find a way to expand the team and open an office in my country. But this is one way of doing it. What are some other ways in which this could be done? Could you just do a cold-calling to companies and do a pitch?

Comment: Almost always, the company owner in the USA, has, a business partner who, is originally, from the developing country.  In the US there are vast numbers of folks from Bangladesh, etc etc (every "developing country" you can list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely yes and, also, absolutely no.

No: The offshore offices are not setup on a whim, they take some planning. Local labour laws, prices, education levels and timezones factor in. The idea is for the company to save money and not lose control of it's internal technologies at the same time. So the large company is not going to have time for someone it doesn't know.

Yes: Sales people do cold-calling all the time, but unless you're part of an established firm with a track record, it's going to be hard to pickup the phone and convince someone.

The management of your local offices might be locals, but they're probably wealthy locals who networked with senior members of the larger companies (as, say, management consultants).